# Getting illegal access error after upgrading the reactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, electron

I was working on the older react electron project. In that react/electron node version are too older.At below you can see the older project package version.

```html
"React" : 15.6.1
"react-dom": "15.6.1"
"react-redux": "^4.4.5",
"react-router": "^3.0.0",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.6",
"react-sortable-hoc": "^0.4.12",
"redux": "^3.6.0",
"redux-logger": "^2.7.0",
"redux-saga": "^0.14.3",
"electron": "1.7.8
"webpack": "1.14.0",
"webpack-merge": "^0.14.1",
"webpack-target-electron-renderer": "^0.4.0"
```

I have updated all of the packages and make app compatible with the all latest package but some times while doing any of action it throw a error like below image.

I have put unsafe before  react lifecycle deprecated hooks too.Can anyone guide me to fix this issue.

latest package version

```html
    "webpack": "^5.11.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.7.2",
    "webpack-target-electron-renderer": "^0.4.0"
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.4.2",
    "react-color": "^2.11.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-electron-web-view": "^2.0.0",
    "react-ga": "^2.2.0",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^4.5.3",
    "react-lazy-load": "^3.1.13",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router": "^3.2.6",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^1.11.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^2.7.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.2",
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There issue is related to nodeJS side.This error happens after upgrading a electron version and electron is combination of node and chromium.
Just need to false these are key while creating a browser window.

```html
const windowOptions = { width: 581, height: 626, minHeight: 500, minWidth: 500, show: false, backgroundColor: '#F1F2F3', webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true, nodeIntegrationInSubFrames: false, nodeIntegrationInWorker: false, } }
```

Refer this URL https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/29169